# How do I know if my firewall is on?

Tags: firewall

I installed Firestarter, and configured my firewall.

But I'm in doubt : On boot, I sometimes see a [FAIL] marker, and to the left, I guess it was something like "start firewall". I can't  be sure because the message is seen for less than a second, so I wanted to know if there is a way, without starting the whole firestarter software, to know if the firewall is on and working, or not.

Either a gadget, or better, some console instruction, the exact name of the firewall process/daemon, or bash script, will do.

**Edit:** I already tested my computer with the "Shield's Up" http://www.grc.com feature, which marks my computer as "Stealth", but as I am behind a router, I'm not surprised. Still, apparently, my computer answers to pings... Strange...

Comment: The Ubuntu firewall will let pings through unless you specifically configure it to do otherwise.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: This question has helpful, upvoted answers and consequently is not *abandoned*. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 49):

There are basically 2 ways of seeing if the firewall is configured. You should use both of the methods and verify that the firewall is both configured and configured the way you wish it to be.

First, check that the firewall rules have been applied. Pretty much all modern Linux firewall solutions use iptables for firewall. You can see that there are rules in place with iptables command:

```
iptables -L
```

This will return the current set of rules. There can be a few rules in the set even if your firewall rules haven't been applied. Just look for lines that match your given rulesets. This will give you an idea of what rules have been entered to the system. this doesn't guarantee the validity of the rules, only that they have been understood.

Next, you will use a second computer to test for connections against the host in question. This can be easily done with the `nmap` command (found in nmap package). Quick and dirty way of checking is:

```
nmap -P0 10.0.0.10
nmap -P0 -sU 10.0.0.10
```

Replace the IP address 10.0.0.10 with your destination hosts IP address.

The first line will scan for TCP ports that are open and available from the second computer. Second line will repeat the scan but this time with UDP ports. -P0 flag will prevent the host from being tested with a ICMP Echo packet, but might be blocked by your firewall rules.

The scan might take a while so be patient. There is also a GUI frontend for nmap called `zenmap` which makes it a bit easier to interpret the scan results if there is a lot of output.

Comment: Using another computer was something I would like to avoid (I am behind an external router, which works as a firewall. I already use the firewall testing from http://www.grc.com which could be considered as "another computer". Still, thanks for the console instructions.

Comment: Zenmap seems to give complicated logs, but it is awesome! Thanks for the info. +1, of course.

Comment: Worth noting that is should be `sudo iptables -L`. Otherwise, you will get "command not found", at least on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 38):

You can use this command:

```
ufw status
```

Comment: Note that this only works if you have ufw installed and using it.

Comment: ufw is install by default on ubuntu, whether or not you are using it, it tells you the status.

Comment: warning: ufw uses iptables to set firewall rules, but 'ufw status' does not show any additional rules created directly by iptables (not using ufw). For instance, the docker daemon by default happily punches holes in the firewall using iptables, but ufw does not show these!.

Comment: I would like to say ufw is just a configuration tool, not actually a firewall. and by default it is disabled.

Comment: I think this command tells you if `ufw` itself is enbled or not. The proof is that if you set the firewall with `iptables` then run `ufw status` it will still  returns `Status: inactive`

Comment: `sudo ufw status` It will need to be the sudo user

Answer (score 10):

To check Firewall status use command:

```
sudo ufw status
```

To enable the firewall use command:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

To disable the firewall use command:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you can review the syslog for any error messages from services with `sudo less /var/log/syslog`. That may give you a clue as to why the firestarter service didn't start.

You can manipulate services with the `service` command. To check whether a service runs, use `service [service_name] status`. In your case, I guess `service_name` is just `firestarter`. You can use tab-completion to get a list of available services (`service TAB TAB`), or take a look at the contents of directory `/etc/init.d` (every file is a script to manage a service).

Ubuntu has its own firewall system, called [Uncomplicated Firewall](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) (ufw). Maybe it's easier to use that one within Ubuntu. If you install the package [`gufw`](http://gufw.tuxfamily.org/), you can access the configuration in *System -> Administration -> Firewall configuration*.

The `iptables` command mentioned above works on any Linux system. All Linux firewall configuration tools (like ufw, firestarter, and many others) are basically front-ends to iptables.

Answer (score 0):

**Question** On boot, I sometimes see a [FAIL] marker, and to the left, I guess it was something like "start firewall". *I can't be sure because the message is seen for less than a second*

*All the above answers are complete in themselves and can solve the problem.
But here's a little advice from me*

Before we start our debugging process, we must analyze the problem description carefully, **so you can use slow motion mode of mobile's camera to see what exactly is the error message.**